# Wordpress , Where file can I find this function

Tags: wordpress-theming

Wordpress , Where file can I find this function[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SRqIa.jpg)

Comment: We are not a code finding service.  Refer to [ask], questions posted here should provide a [MCVE], and please complete the 2-minute tour before posting again.

Comment: Perhaps suspicious two upvotes here? Anyway, there's no function there as far as I can see, and it's off-topic.